# How to deny user to access a page by entering URL directly using PHP?

Tags: php

I developed a application that have different user logins and they have different privileges by their category.The problem is when one is logged in and then he enters a URL of denied page he got access...!
What I should do it's so dangerous.
I written the code like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['login_type']) )
    {
       header("Location:logout.php");
       exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: use a similar session flag and set it when user redirects to some specific page

Comment: @Babar can you explain it in more detail.

Comment: Are both pages with login forms right? Make some of them send a specific POST/GET value, then in PHP you can check either it has some specific value or not.

Comment: @holpducki : I think when I runs the application disable browser's URL field for only that tab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing in that code is checking if a `username` and `login_type` exists in the SESSION array. Those should be set for any logged in user.

Now you need to change the code to ask what `login_type` this user is!

For example:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['login_type']) )
    {
       header("Location:logout.php");
       exit;
    }
    if ( $_SESSION['login_type'] != 'ADMIN' ) {
       // This is an admin only page.
       header("Location: you-are-not-allowed.php");
       exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: can we check URL in if condition? If yes, this will more helpful to me. e.g. for doctor user: if(URL==abc) eho "not allowed";

Comment: Not enough information provided for me to make any sort of suggestion in that area!